# NGINX vs. Apache? What to choose when deploying react

Tags: apache, reactjs, tomcat, nginx

I am new to reactjs. I created a basic react app using `create-react-app` boilerplate. I prepared the build by running the command `npm run build`.

Now I want to host the build folder. Which is better and why.

Please let me know if any better and easy option available as I am new to this.

Answer (score 0):

Whatever is available to you will do just fine. When you run `npm run build static` it will create static files that you are able to host from whatever web-server you want. If you are curious about performance numbers, they are negligibly different in this case. Just choose whatever platform you feel most comfortable with.

Comment: When I host problems are coming like font-awesome CSS not found and many more

Comment: Are you hosting in an HTTPS environment? Because if not some HTTPS resources won't load in HTTP.

Comment: How can I check environment @DanielAbdelsamed